# Installing dependencies/libraries for EMR for spark-shell

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark

I am trying add extra libraries to scala used through spark-shell through the Elsatic MapReduce inatance. But I am unsure how to go by this, is there a build tool that is used when spark-shell runs?

All i need to do is install a scala library and have it run through the spark-shell version of scala, Im not sure how to go about this since Im not sure how the EMR instance installs scala and spark.

Comment: Okay, i added a bit more. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this answer will evolve with the information you give. As for now, considering that you have AWS EMR cluster deployed on which you wish to use the spark-shell. There is many options :

**Option 1 :** You can copy your libraries to the cluster with the `scp` command and add them into your spark-shell with the `--jars` options. e.g :

from your local machine :

```
scp -i awskey.pem /path/to/jar/lib.jar hadoop@emr-cluster-address:/path/to/destination
```

on your EMR cluster :

```
spark-shell --master yarn --jars lib.jar
```

Spark uses the following URL scheme to allow different strategies for disseminating jars:

- file: - Absolute paths and file:/ URIs are served by the driver’s HTTP file server, and every executor pulls the file from the driver HTTP server.
- hdfs:, http:, https:, ftp: - these pull down files and JARs from the URI as expected
- local: - a URI starting with local:/ is expected to exist as a local file on each worker node. This means that no network IO will be incurred, and works well for large files/JARs that are pushed to each worker, or shared via NFS, GlusterFS, etc.

**Option 2 :** You can have a copy of your libraries from S3 and add them with --jars option.

**Option 3 :** You can use the `--packages` options to load it from remote repository. You can include any other dependencies by supplying a comma-delimited list of maven coordinates. All transitive dependencies will be handled when using this command. Additional repositories (or resolvers in SBT) can be added in a comma-delimited fashion with the flag --repositories. These commands can be used with pyspark, spark-shell, and spark-submit to include Spark Packages.

For Python, the equivalent --py-files option can be used to distribute .egg, .zip and .py libraries to executors.

Comment: Great thanks. This works but I am not able to get what I want to actually happen so I'll just have to open a new question I think.

Comment: Another idea to copy your files to S3: aws s3 cp my_full_local_path my_full_s3_path. https://aws.amazon.com/fr/cli/

Comment: that's option 2. Thanks @belka

Comment: @eliasah I meant using the Amazon CLI, its not specified in your option 2 as far as I understand. Your option 2 is about using the Amazon S3 GUI.

Comment: It's implied. AWS has many APIs to manage/communicate with it's services. There is not point in describing them all. ;)

Comment: @eliasah Like we say in French, tastes and colors ;) Anyhow, thanks for your answer I think it'll save my day.